# Prove that union of intervals does not represent an interval, while intersection does

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

> Let X and Y be intervals. Is X ∩ Y an interval? What about X ∪ Y?

I guess, although I am not completely sure, that the answer to this question is that the union of 2 intervals does not stand for an interval, while the intersection does, but how to prove it?

Also I note that the intersection between 2 intervals can yield an empty set.

Comment: To prove some statement is false, you just need to find a single counter example. If you want to show union of two intervals need not be an interval, you just random cook up some intervals (as simple as possible) and try. Say $[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]$,... wait, $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ isn't a interval, we are done...

Comment: This may depend on how liberal you take the term "interval". Is $\emptyset$ an interval?

Comment: I would say that an empty set is not an interval, in fact...

Comment: Actually, it is - or can be, depending on just how "interval" is defined for a discussion (or course, paper, book). Consider [0, 0), or (0, 0). If *is* an interval according to your working definition then it's a degenerate one, and it's in practice it's no trouble.

Comment: The title of the question is not well-phrased, and may be confusing you. It should say something like: Prove that the union of intervals is not necessarily an interval, but the intersection of intervals is (an interval)". The union of certain intervals *is* an interval: $(1,2) \cup [0,3]$, or $(1,3) \cup [2,4)$; however, the union of others is not. (If you provide an example of that then you'ved proved the first part of the question.)

Comment: yes, I wanted to edit the title but the website doesn't allow me it. It says that it isn't good to make many changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** To prove that the union is not necessarily an interval, just give a counterexample.

To prove that the intersection is an interval, suppose $a,b\in X\cap Y$. Then in particular, $a,b\in X$. Since $X$ is an interval, what does that mean regarding $a$ and $b$ (and points "between" them)? Likewise with $Y$.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure I have understood the second part, with respect to showing that intersection is an interval

Comment: What does it mean for $X$ to be an interval? And what would it mean for you to say that any other set (like $X\cap Y$) is an interval?

Comment: As I understood, we can say that an interval is a range of numbers without discontinuities... Am I answering to your question?

Comment: I think a set $S$ of real numbers is an interval if and only if $[a,b]\subset S$ whenever $a,b\in S$. Note that $S$ may be infinite or degenerate and may contain any number (including none) of its (real) endpoints. So now do you see that $X\cap Y$ inherits this property from $X$ (or $Y$) since $X\cap Y\subset X$?