# Evaluate this statement / find the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intersection-theory

$X = (\{1\}\cup\{2,3\})\cap(0,4)$

I think the solution is an empty set but I would like confirmation or refutation from you.

I think it is an empty set because we take the union of 2 sets containing just those elements: $1,2,3$ and then we search for the intersection with the open interval $(0,4)$ - which means that 0 and 4 are not included. Thus, the 2 intervals share $1,2,3$ ... now, I feel even more confused but I keep thinking that the solution is an empty set. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong: $1,2$, and $3$ are all elements of the interval $(0,4)$, so $X=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Yes, I was undecided about these 2 answers...:)

Comment: What about if I would take only the union  ({1}∪{2,3}). What would it be the result? = {1,2,3} or would the expression remain as is written? = {1}∪{2,3} ? Just for learning something I might need

Comment: @Mario: You can write it either way--they are the same set--but it is probably more convenient to write it as $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: You could certainly simplify $\{1\}\cup\{2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$, yes.

Comment: is {1,2,3} an interval?

Comment: Check the definition of "interval" and you'll see that it is not. For example, it contains 2 and 3 but nothing between them. A question for you: Is $\{1\}$ an interval?

Comment: I think the question is not well-worded if it asks for *an* interval. You can certainly write the set $\{1,2,3\}$ as the union of *degenerate* (single real number) intervals: $[1,1]\cup[2,2]\cup[3,3]$, but this is ugly!

Comment: I agree the title isn't well-phrased. "Find the interval..." implies that it is an interval. But it seems the question is just, What set is the expression on the right? @Marconius Re [1,1] etc., yes that's what I was getting at (I was asking OP to think about it). Right, you *could* write it that way but it's an odd way to talk.

Comment: Thank you for answering! You are right, I should take some time to study in deeper way the theory and I will! I understood that is not an interval - but I guessed so - because there is no continuity between the elements.

Comment: @BrianO: Well, that depends on the overlying ordered set. For example, $\{1,2,3\}$ is an interval *in the integers*, but certainly not in the rational numbers or the real numbers.

Comment: @Cameron Buie Sure. But I assume we're in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. (and: "*underlying*" ordered set)

Comment: @BrianO: As do I.

Comment: @CameronBuie Happily, the intersection is the same in all three ;/

Comment: Well, this my last question, added in the comments, is important for me as it is linked to this other recent question I made http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483597/prove-that-union-of-intervals-does-not-represent-an-interval-while-intersection

Comment: One more thing: Your question says "an empty set", repeatedly. There is only one empty set. Reason: sets are identical *iff* they contain exactly the same elements. So: *the empty set*, pretty much always.

Comment: Actually, also the title of the question I have linked is not well phrased because I can prove whatever I want, if what I state sounds logical. I mean, if we agree that {1,2,3} is an interval in the integer numbers, although not in R, then I can prove that the union of 2 sets is also an interval

Comment: Here, I think an acceptable answer just states what the value of $X$ is.

Comment: Ok @BrianO , but can someone of you give an answer to that question... I feel that the question of the link can be answered in more than one way or am I wrong?

Comment: You mean, the question "show that union of intervals isn't necessarily an interval but the intersection of intervals is"?

Comment: yes! that question, exactly. It is also more interesting than this one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30363/discussion-between-mario-vald-and-briano).